# Find all intervals of uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{nx^2+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

*Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the sequence of functions given by: $f_n(x) = \dfrac{nx}{nx^2+1}$. Determine whether the sequence converges pointwise and find all intervals of uniform convergence*.

I have shown that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise but I' having trouble proving uniform convergence

---

**My attempt**

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $f_n(0)=0$. And for $x \neq 0$: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{nx}{nx^2+1} = \dfrac{1}{x}$, so the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \text{ if } x = 0\\
\dfrac{1}{x}, \text{ if } x \neq 0\end{cases}$$

Since $f$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ the sequence $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ to $f$.

I would want to show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $\dfrac{1}{x}$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0, \infty)$. What I've seen so far is that:

$$\left \vert f_n(x) - \dfrac{1}{x} \right \vert = \left \vert \dfrac{nx}{nx^2+1}-\dfrac{1}{x}\right \vert = \left \vert \dfrac{-1}{x(nx^2+1)}\right \vert$$

I know that if $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}- \{ 0\}} \left \vert f_n(x) - \dfrac{1}{x} \right \vert \to 0$ then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly, but $\dfrac{-1}{x(nx^2+1)}$ is not bounded, so how can I find the intervals of uniform convergence?

Comment: For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$$ \dfrac{-1}{x(nx^2+1)}$ is not bounded. Does that mean that the sequence does not converge uniformly anywhere?

Comment: If you consider closed intervals that don't include zero, you can bound the error, but you can't have intervals including zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning so far is correct. You are left with showing that
$$\sup_{x\in I} \frac{1}{|nx^2 + 1||x|} \to 0$$
for your desired interval $I$.

Now, if you take an interval which is arbitrarily close to $0$, as in for example $I = (0;+\infty)$, you would intuitively guess that you get uniform convergence (since the interval does not contain the problematic point $0$), however, this is not the case. Since $x\in (0;+\infty)$ can approach $0$ arbitrarily closely, you can take e.g. $x=1/\sqrt{n}\in(0;+\infty)$ to get
$$\sup_{x\in I} \frac{1}{|nx^2 + 1||x|} \geq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\to+\infty,$$
i.e. we don't have uniform convergence.

If you want to assure uniform convergence, you want to *stay away* from $0$. Any interval $I = [a;+\infty)$ for $a>0$ (or subsets thereof) will work (analogously $I = (-\infty; -a]$), since now $x\in I$ satisfies $|x|\geq a$, so that
$$\sup_{x\in I} \frac{1}{|nx^2 + 1||x|} \leq \frac{1}{(na^2 + 1)(a)} \to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the function $f_n$ is odd it suffices to consider $x\ge 0.$ For $x\ge a>0$ we have
$$0\le {1\over x}-f_n(x)={1\over x}-{nx\over nx^2+1}={1\over x(nx^2+1)}\le {1\over a^3n}$$
By the Weierstrass majorization test the convergence is uniform on $[a,\infty),$ $a>0.$ The convergence is not uniform on $(0,a)$, $a>0,$ as for each $n$ the function $${1\over x}-f_n(x)={1\over x(nx^2+1)}$$ is unbounded on $(0,a).$